# using extension methods with mono

Tags: c#, mono, extension-methods

How do I add a reference to System.Core.dll assembly?

I am trying to compile an extension method using mono. I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace My.Util
{
    public static class SocketReturnTypeCovariants
    {
        public static IPEndPoint RemoteEndPoint_safe(this Socket soc)
        {
            return soc.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error.

```
/home/richard/d/trash/mono/return-type-covariance/return-type-covariance/Main.cs(34,34): Error CS1110: `My.Util.SocketReturnTypeCovariants.RemoteEndPoint_safe(this System.Net.Sockets.Socket)': Extension methods cannot be declared without a reference to System.Core.dll assembly. Add the assembly reference or remove `this' modifer from the first parameter (CS1110) (return-type-covariance)
```

So how do I add a reference to System.Core.dll assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the references of your project (right click on "References" in MonoDevelop's solution explorer) and find System.Core in the Global Assembly Cache tab. Check the box next to it and click "OK"

Comment: also check that you're referencing at least .NET 3.0 - you can do this in the Project Properties, under Build if I remember correctly

Answer (score -2):

// Is it as easy as this?

using System.Core;

Comment: `using` does not add an assembly reference. It just makes the types in already references assemblies in than namespace accessible by a shorter name because you don't need to specify the namespace anymore.